# SPOJ Prime Generator

Tags: python

I guess this isn't the best question in the world, but I can't seem to figure why on earth this code:

```
def isprime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for divisor in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if num % divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True


def case(mini, maxi):
    for i in range(mini, maxi + 1):
        if isprime(i):
            print(i)


test = [line.split() for line in input().split("\n")[1:]]
for line in test:
    mini, maxi = [int(num) for num in line]
    case(mini, maxi)
    print()
```

does not satisfy [SPOJ Question 2](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/)?? The prime tester has worked well for me before, and the code works on the example inputs.

Comment: does it meet the time and memory limits?

Comment: @immortal It easily meets the memory limits. As for the time limits, I do not know because it doesn't run for long enough before reporting an error.

Comment: What error is reported? please add the error to the question

Comment: First of all, if you find which number is prime using isprime in your code , you will definetely get TLE. You have to use Sieve of Eratosthenes .. here is the link for that : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes